# What would be a good substitution for powdered milk in cereal cookies?

Tags: substitutions

In a TV show, a recipe was used that its main ingredient was corn flakes. I don't know if it has a name but it calls for caster sugar, butter, corn flakes and milk powder.

[It's called Cornflake crunch, apparently!](http://www.marthastewart.com/865366/cornflake-crunch)

What is a good substitute of powdered milk? I'd go for powdered infant formula, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Gigili, half of your question was a recipe request. Only a recipe can tell you what amounts of the ingredients to use. And even if recipe requests were allowed - which they are not - nobody can know which one of hundreds of possible recipes this show used. The substitution part is fine, so I edited the recipe request out and left the substitution.

Comment: Why don't you want to use milk powder? Do you have a dairy allergy, is milk powder hard to get where you live, do you not enjoy the taste of it, ...? Suggesting substitutions is impossible without knowing the reason for the substitute

Comment: How about liquid milk ;)

Comment: @KateGregory: Unfortunately I can't get hold of it where I live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that infant formula would be a reasonable substitute for powdered milk in your recipe.

The inclusion of powdered milk here is to provide the *taste* of milk to go with the cereal component of the cookies (so they're actually sweetened cereal and milk cookies that crunch - not just cereal crunch cookies) - so the real milk *taste* of the powdered milk is important.  Admittedly, as an adult, I have not tried powdered infant formula, but I would be willing to wager that, either dry or reconstituted, it does NOT taste like the milk you put on cereal.

Also, I would be wary of how the ingredients in infant formula would react when heated in an oven over time.  Different infant formulas have different compositions - typically they have some components isolated from cow's milk, but add other ingredients to achieve a desirable consistency, nutritional balance, and vitamin/mineral content.  There probably isn't much research to help you predict what happens when you bake dried infant formula - you might not want to be the first to take the risk.

Basically, I wouldn't risk substituting a primary flavor component of your recipe with something else - I think you should stick with the powdered milk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you're right about infant formula, but -as weird as it sounds- I've got the idea from a pizza dough recipe that calls for infant formula.

Comment: In a pizza dough recipe (1) the primary purpose of the infant formula would NOT be milk taste like it is in the cookies, & (2) the formula would be thoroughly hydrated in the pizza dough and not as likely to react unexpectedly from the heat in the oven (the recipe for the cookies has almost no liquid whatsoever - just a little bit from what is in the butter).  I would think of this more like processed cheese-food slices - they vaguely resemble cheese, but they don't really taste like cheese and when you broil them, they turn strange colors and don't always melt and sometimes smoke and stink.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer and comment, I really appreciate it.